# Getting run time error for Depth first search in c++ code

Tags: c++, function, graph, runtime, depth-first-search

I have an un-directed graph. I am trying to find the maximum node value other than the adjacent ones of a given node.

For example :

```
6 // number of nodes

1 3

2 3

3 4

4 5

4 6// edges
```

I have to find the maximum node value other than the direct adjacent nodes for the node in question.

For example, if I use DFS(1) the answer must be 6. My code is working perfectly fine but if I call DFS() multiple times in suffering run time error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<list>
#include<map>
#include<utility>
#include<vector>
class graph
{
    std::list<int> *adj;
    int V;
public:
    graph(int V);
    void add(int v, int w);
    void DFS(int s);
};
int max = -1;
graph::graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new std::list<int>[V];
}
void graph::add(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w);
    adj[w].push_back(v);
}
void graph::DFS(int s)
{
    std::vector<int> visited(V, false);
    std::stack<int> st;
    st.push(s);
    while (!st.empty())
    {
        int t = st.top();
        st.pop();
        if (!visited[t])
        {
            visited[t] = true;
        }
        for (auto i = adj[t].begin(); i != adj[t].end(); i++)
        {
            if (!visited[*i])
            {
                visited[*i] = true;
            }

        }
        for (int j = V; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (visited[j] == 0)
            {
                std::cout << j << " ";
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
int main()
{
    int t = 0, k = 0;
    graph g(6);

    g.add(1, 3);

    g.add(2, 3);

    g.add(3, 4);

    g.add(4, 5);

    g.add(5, 6);

    g.DFS(1);
    g.DFS(2);
    g.DFS(3);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You are unfortunate to get that far. In the `graph` constructor `adj = new std::list<int>[V];` makes an array of `list` of size `V`. `V` is specified as 6. Later ` g.add(5, 6);` attempts to `adj[w].push_back(v);` which resolves to `adj[6].push_back(5);` and writes outside the array. Arrays are origin 0, so an array of size 6 is index-able from 0 to 5.

Comment: @user4581301
Thanks a lot understood the bug.